# Ember reload component after model's object was changed

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, components

I have some problems with EmberJS' bindings.

I have a component named **x-colorpicker**.
It renders on page load. And binds to *model.rate.color* attribute.
How can I reload this component after something like:

```
this.model.set('rate', that.store.createRecord('model', params));
```

Comment: If you are passing the `model.rate.color` down to the component it should trigger a re-render when the property changes, you will need to add the relevant code here or reproduce the problem https://ember-twiddle.com/

Comment: It should work. Please provide more code.